# MySQL using index issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have a big table which has around 7 million records. (MySQL)

Columns go like;

```
id | atype | textbody | ....
```

id is primary key, atype is index

when I run

```
select * from tablename where `atype`='doit'
```

it uses atype index. (there are 1.7 million doit rows in the table)

but when I run this query

```
select * from tablename where `atype`='doit' or `atype`='payment'
```

it doesn't use the index. I only says possible_index is atype. (there are 168 payment rows in the table)

is there any explanation of this behaviour?

If i run this query;

```
select * from tablename where `atype`='paymentfailed' or `atype`='payment'
```

It uses atype index.

so whenever I use 'doit', it doesn't use atype index

Comment: Of what use is an index if you try to grab 1.7 million records?

Comment: select * from tablename where `atype`='doit' -> 1.7 million records 
select * from tablename where `atype`='payment' -> 168 records 
select * from tablename -> 7 million records

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is rather finicky about indexes.  I think it is smarter about `IN` rather than `OR`:

```
select *
from tablename
where `atype` in ('doit', 'payment');
```

If that doesn't work, then use `union all`:

```
select *
from tablename
where `atype` = 'doit'
union all
select *
from tablename
where `atype` = 'payment';
```

Comment: I tried IN too, still says possible_keys atype but key null

Comment: and yes I tried union too, union uses the index, I want to know why it doesn't use the index for other queries?

Comment: I just updated the question and added a bit more details

Comment: @HakanMeytan . . . The choice of indexes may depend on statistics that MySQL gathers about the table.  It might not use an index for `'doit'` because it is so frequent that an index is not worthwhile.